# Stuck in loading window collectively using KIVY

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, attributeerror, builder

Am following along on a POS tutorial using Python and Kivy, and am stuck on this error that seemes to disappear and keeps reappearing. I have a main.py file in which I attempt to load a window admin.py that throws the attribute error

```
  File "C:/Users/John/PycharmProjects/FirstKivyApplication/main.py", line 3, in <module>
     from Admin.admin import AdminWindow
   File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\FirstKivyApplication\Admin\admin.py", line 22, in <module>
     Builder.load_file('Admin/admin.kv')
   File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\FirstKivyApplication\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\FirstKivyApplication\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 399, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\FirstKivyApplication\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 130, in __getattr__
     raise AttributeError
 AttributeError
```

MAIN.PY

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from Admin.admin import AdminWindow
from Signin.signin import SignInWindow
from Operator.theoperator import OperatorWindow

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

   admin_widget = AdminWindow() #An instance of our Admin wdindow
   signin_widget = SignInWindow() # An instance of our sign in window
   operator_widget = OperatorWindow() # An instance of our Operator window

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.ids.scrn_si.add_widget(self.signin_widget)
    self.ids.scrn_admin.add_widget(self.admin_widget)
    self.ids.scrn_op.add_widget(self.operator_widget)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sa = MainApp()
    sa.run()
```

ADMIN.PY

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('Admin/admin.kv')

class Notify(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size_hint = (.3, .3)


class AdminWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def logout(self):
        self.parent.parent.current = 'scrn_si'

class AdminApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AdminWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AdminApp().run()
```

And here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten this statement below in the relative kv file.

```
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
```